# JQuery Mobile: Dynamic Listview + Checkbox in a mess at the first time display

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have following code to dynamically add checkbox in a listview. At the first display, it shows a messy formatting like in the picture 1. If I click on refresh button, which called the same code to update the listview's content, it become correct like in the picture 2.

Do i missed something? 
Thanks

Pic1: http://postimage.org/image/6bvo8fpdd/
Pic2: http://postimage.org/image/gnyuokteb/

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">


<div data-role="content" align="center">    
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"><input type="radio" name="q1" id="checkall" value="checkall"/><label for="checkall">Check All</label><input type="radio" name="q1" id="uncheckall" value="uncheckall" checked="checked"/><label for="uncheckall">Uncheck All</label></fieldset>
    <p>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" >                                                             
    <ul id="mylist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-count-theme="b" data-filter="true" ">            

    </ul>
    </fieldset>
    </p>                   
</div>
```

```
function showCode(refresh){
var output ='';
var iCounter = 0;


$('#mylist').empty();

for (var i = 0; (i < g_Data.length && iCounter < 10); i+=2 ) {
            iCounter += 1;

            output += '<li><input type="checkbox" name="chk-'+iCounter + 'a" id="chx-'+iCounter +'a" class="custom" />'+ g_Data[i]+'<span class="ui-li-count">' + g_Data[i+1] + '</span></li>';

        }

$('#mylist').append(output).listview('refresh');}
```

Comment: your jquery is loading before the elements that it is formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling "refresh" for your list view, try to call "create" function for
your page.

Some thing like this:

```
// refresh list
$('#mylist').append(output).listview('refresh');

// refresh page
$('#page2').trigger('create');
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. For the time being, I've fixed by calling the display code twice, 1 by user clicking the button, and again by the "onpageshow" event of that page.